# Powerful Octagon

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, optimization, number-theory, graph-theory

Place different integers on the vertices of an octagon so that the sum of the integers in any two vertices joined by one of its edges is a power of 2. Do so in such a way that the largest integer used is as small as possible.

Do likewise on the vertices of a decagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible arrangement:

> 6, -4, 5, -1, 2, 0, 4, -2

Proof of optimality:

> Here is the graph for integers $\leq 5$:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Note that integers $\leq -4$ do not occur, as each one can connect to at most one integer $\leq 5$.
>
>  The graph is so simple that an exhaustive analysis can be done to show that there is no simple loop of length $8$.
>
>
>  Slightly better proof:
>
>
>  We look at the edge connecting 0 and 4. If this edge is used in the loop, then at least one of 1, 2 cannot present in the loop, and at least one of -2, -3 cannot present in the loop. This results in at most $7$ numbers in the loop.
>
>
>  Now assume that the edge connecting 0 and 4 is not used in the loop. We may thus delete that edge from the graph.
>
>
>  Since the loop is of length $8$, one number does not belong to the loop. However, in the current graph, removing any number will result in one of its neighbors having at most $1$ edge. Hence that neighbor cannot occur in the loop either. This leads to at most $7$ numbers in the loop.

In view of the answer by loopy walt, this also proves optimality for the case of decagon.

Answer (score 2):

My best shot:

> ```
>           5
>       3      -3
>
>    -2           4
>
>       6       0
>           2
> ```

And for 10:

> ```
>         6  -4
>     -2         5
>
>    3            -3
>
>     -1         4
>         2   0
> ```